How to get the list of all reports/datasets that plug to a dataset or dataflow (across workspaces)?
In my workspace I have a few datasets and dataflows.
When I click on lineage for a dataset or a dataflow, then it only gives me the workplace level info of what all points to it.
It doesn't show me the reports/datasets located in other workspaces that plug to this dataset or data flow. How to get this list?

Go to Impact Analysis :

A new tab will be open in the right side :

You can browse by item type :

Or you can browse by workspace :

Based on the documentation :

When you make changes to a semantic model, or are considering making
changes, it's important to be able to assess the potential impact of
those changes on downstream reports and dashboards that depend on that
semantic model. Semantic model impact analysis provides you with
information that can help you make this assessment.
It shows you how many workspaces, reports, and dashboards might be
affected by your change, and provides easy navigation to the
workspaces where the affected reports and dashboards are located so
that you can investigate further. It shows you how many unique
visitors and the number of views there are on the potentially affected
items. This helps you determine the overall impact of the change for
the downstream item. For instance, it's probably more important to
investigate the effect of a change on a report that has 20,000 unique
viewers than it is to investigate the effect of the change on a report
that has three viewers. It provides an easy way to notify the relevant
people about a change you made or are thinking about making.


Update :
I also found this :
The lineage information is available also via Power BI Rest APIs. The APIs are available for both Power BI service admins and other users.
If you’re an admin, you have access to all the workspaces metadata, and therefore you can create a cross-workspaces lineage view. Here is the best practice we recommend on to get this information:

GetGroupsAsAdmin API with $expand to get all artifact information.
To get lineage between dashboards and reports, use GetDashboardsAsAdmin with $expand=tiles.
Use GetDatasources for Datasets and GetDatasources for Dataflows to connect datasets and dataflows and their data sources.
On the new workspaces, a dataflow can be linked to another dataflow. To get this type of connections use GetUpstreamDataflows for Dataflows.

Admin - Dataflows GetUpstreamDataflowsInGroupAsAdmin

Do you have any information on simple example of how to use these apis
